# shapely convex_hull problem

Tags: python, shapely, convex-hull

I produced a polygon from the points in the image using the convex_hull function of the shapely library, but it could not produce the polygon as desired. The green polygon is the desired result, while the black polygon is the result polygon. How can I get a shape like a green polygon in Python?
[image]

Comment: No problem with the convex hull. The black polygon is the convex hull of the points. The green polygon is not a convex hull. You should search for "concave hull" or "alpha shape".

Comment: It's relevant -> [Calculate bounding polygon of alpha shape from the Delaunay triangulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23073170/calculate-bounding-polygon-of-alpha-shape-from-the-delaunay-triangulation)

Comment: Teşekkür ederim Kadir hocam, concave_hull aslında aradığım çözüm gibiymiş.